# Function and looping in training and testing set using r

Tags: r

I have multiple time series and a single time series data runs from 1937 - 1966 and I want to run a loop in every single time series and build a simple model on training set (the first 20 set and the remaining 10 sets used as testing set and I use the testing set to predict a simple mean model. Any assistance is appreciated!
Data (I have around 30 multiple time series data and here under you get the first 3 time series data):

```
    Plot    Species Year    Count   Ppt Temp
A      BG  1937    81  33.90833333 14.13181818
A   BG  1938    45  48.18333333 15.14727273
A   BG  1939    96  39.95833333 14.92
A   BG  1940    44  48.36666667 14.27363636
A   BG  1941    24  57.975  14.02
A   BG  1942    8   59.55   13.65727273
A    BG  1943    28  38.3    14.28363636
…………………………………….
A BG 1966  30      33.5          12.366666

A  BD  1937    135 33.90833333 14.13181818
A   BD  1938    91  48.18333333 15.14727273
A   BD  1939    171 39.95833333 14.92
A   BD  1940    88  48.36666667 14.27363636
A   BD  1941    59  57.975  14.02
A   BD  1942    1   59.55   13.65727273
A   BD  1943    1   38.3    14.28363636
……………………………………………………..
A BD   1966   36     28         15.23658

B   BG  1937    34  33.90833333 14.13181818
B   BG  1938    16  48.18333333 15.14727273
B   BG  1939    19  39.95833333 14.92
B   BG  1940    35  48.36666667 14.27363636
B  BG  1941    32  57.975  14.02
B   BG  1942    7   59.55   13.65727273
B  BG  1943    2   38.3    14.28363636
------------------------------------
B BG 1966  4 25   12.259
```

My code is:

```
    data$groups <- paste(data$Plot, data$Species, sep = "_")
data_by_plot <- split (data$Count, data$groups)
ly <- lapply(data_by_plot, function(df)){
D<-nrow(df)
Training<-D[1:20,]
Testing<-D[20:30,]
Mean_model<-lm(count~1, data = Training)
Prediction<-Testing$Count[i]- Mean_model$coefficients
)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subsetting from `D` which is just 1 number. Probably you were trying to do :

```
ly <- lapply(data_by_plot, function(df) {
  Training<-df[1:20,]
  Testing<-df[20:30,]
  Mean_model<-lm(count~1, data = Training)
  Prediction<-Testing$Count[i]- Mean_model$coefficients
  return(Prediction)
})
```

Comment: you are a code guru, if I want to use the last row of training set (row 20) and predict using testing set or row 21, and predict 22 of testing set within one interval up to 30, how can I adjust my code? If there was no geographical barrier, I should have bought you a coffee, lol!

Comment: Another challenge, lapply need the data should be equal in dimension, what do you recommend if the data have unequal dimension? Because, I have another variable which uses the difference between the first row and second row and the first row should be either 0 or NA and in this case, my code doesn't work?

Comment: To predict you can add `result <- predict(Mean_model, data = Testing)` in `lapply`.

Comment: That one I got it, but I have another dataset with unequal number of dimnesion and lapply couldn't be applied, do you know another alternative? The above code worked for me for the above data.

Comment: You don't need same dimension to use `lapply`. You can apply it to data of any size.

Comment: @If I want to use the first row training set and apply on the first row testing test, second testing set, fourth testing set and fifth row of testing set, a kind of rolling base,  and the same thing continues using the second row of training set, how can I do that, since you already know my code, thanks, Ronak!

Comment: Can you ask that as a new question, please. Thanks.

Comment: @ Ronak, I asked according to your request but I haven't gotten any try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65251678/partition-of-training-and-testing-sets-in-r