# Partition of training and testing sets in r

Tags: r

In a multiple time, series 1937 - 1966 and I want to run a loop in every single time series and build a simple model on training set (the first 20 set and the remaining 10 sets used as testing set and I use the testing set to predict a simple mean model. I want to partition the training and testing set in the way that I build the model on first row from the last training set and apply on the first-row testing test, second row testing set, fourth row testing set and fifth row of testing set, a kind of rolling base, and the same thing continues using the second row from the last training set….

```
Plot  Species Year    Count   Ppt Temp
A   BG  1937    81  33.90833333 14.13181818
A   BG  1938    45  48.18333333 15.14727273
A   BG  1939    96  39.95833333 14.92
A   BG  1940    44  48.36666667 14.27363636
A   BG  1941    24  57.975  14.02
A   BG  1942    8   59.55   13.65727273
A    BG  1943    28  38.3    14.28363636
…………………………………….
A BG 1966  30      33.5          12.366666

A  BD  1937    135 33.90833333 14.13181818
A   BD  1938    91  48.18333333 15.14727273
A   BD  1939    171 39.95833333 14.92
A   BD  1940    88  48.36666667 14.27363636
A   BD  1941    59  57.975  14.02
A   BD  1942    1   59.55   13.65727273
A   BD  1943    1   38.3    14.28363636
……………………………………………………..
A BD   1966   36     28         15.23658

B   BG  1937    34  33.90833333 14.13181818
B   BG  1938    16  48.18333333 15.14727273
B   BG  1939    19  39.95833333 14.92
B   BG  1940    35  48.36666667 14.27363636
B  BG  1941    32  57.975  14.02
B   BG  1942    7   59.55   13.65727273
B  BG  1943    2   38.3    14.28363636
------------------------------------
B BG 1966  4 25   12.259
```

My code is:

```
    data$groups <- paste(data$Plot, data$Species, sep = "_")
data_by_plot <- split (data$Count, data$groups)
ly <- lapply(data_by_plot, function(df) {
  Training<-df[1:20,]
  Testing<-df[21:30,]
  Mean_model<-lm(count~1, data = Training)
  Prediction<-Testing$Count[i]- Mean_model$coefficients
  return(Prediction)
})
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Which rows do you want to use for training data and which ones do you want to use for predicting? How many rows will be there in the final output? If you could explain this with the help of a small reproducible example it will be easier to understand.

Comment: I have 20 rows for training and the remaining 10 rows for testing set in a single time series but I want to divide the training set again in a two year interval again (from the 20 training set) and predict in the testing set of the first row, second row...