# Getting result of function using common columns in R

Tags: r

This is an extension of question on [Function and looping in training and testing set using r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65156506/function-and-looping-in-training-and-testing-set-using-r/65156539?noredirect=1#comment115346729_65156539).
How to get the result of the **function (func1)** given below in external folder using common columns and then each with its own additional column output? Moreover, how can I get the output of each unique data_by_plot result in external folder. I used `write.table(func1, “c:\\Document\\project\\result)`, but I couldn’t get in the way I want. My code is given below. I tried different ways using **cbind and rbind** but it doesn’t give me what I want.

My code is :

```
    result<- c()
data$groups <- paste(data$Plot, data$Species, sep = "_")
data_by_plot <- split (data$Count, data$groups)
func1<- do.call(rbind, lapply(data_by_plot, function(df){

  Training<-df[1:20,]
  Testing<-df[21:30,]
  Model1<-lm(count~1, data = Training)
  Pred1<-Testing$Count[i]- Model1$coefficients

Model2<-lm(Diff~1, data = Training)
  Pred2<-Testing$Count[i]- Model2$coefficients

Model3<-lm(Diff~1+LogCount, data = Training)
  Pred3<-Testing$Count[i]- Model3$coefficients

Model4<-lm(Diff~1+Count, data = Training)
  Pred4<-Testing$Count[i]- Model4$coefficients
  result <- Reduce(merge, list(Pred1, Pred2, Pred3, Pred4))
  return(result)
})
```

Comment: I don't quite understand - but you want to save the results of the function in a folder? Is the name of the folder/file dependent on something? To create a folder you would use the `dir.create()` command. If you wanted to change the name of each folder created, I suppose you would use something like `name <- <insert the name you want>; path <- <your path>; dir.create(paste0(path, name))`

Comment: @Justin Cocco, thanks, I want to save the result of the function (func1),i.e the result in return (result), I think it is in a form of list, so how can I get the result out and save in external folder in computer. I know how to put in external folder using write.table, but the problem is to pull out the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok with clarification from your comment above. There are two ways you could do this. You could incorporate it into the function itself or pull out the result of the function and pass it to an export function.

I think the easiest way would be the former, so create an export function:

```
export.function <- function(result){
 path <- "//folder/" #whatever your path is to the folder
 as.data.frame(result) -> result #turn to data.frame
 write.csv(paste0(path, result, ".csv"))
 }
```

This will write the result, as a data frame, as a csv in the path designated. (It will name it "result.csv").

Then add it:

```
    result<- c()
data$groups <- paste(data$Plot, data$Species, sep = "_")
data_by_plot <- split (data$Count, data$groups)
func1<- do.call(rbind, lapply(data_by_plot, function(df){

  Training<-df[1:20,]
  Testing<-df[21:30,]
  Model1<-lm(count~1, data = Training)
  Pred1<-Testing$Count[i]- Mean_model$coefficients

Model2<-lm(Diff~1, data = Training)
  Pred2<-Testing$Count[i]- Mean_model$coefficients

Model3<-lm(Diff~1+LogCount, data = Training)
  Pred3<-Testing$Count[i]- Mean_model$coefficients

Model4<-lm(Diff~1+Count, data = Training)
  Pred4<-Testing$Count[i]- Mean_model$coefficients
  result <- Reduce(merge, list(Pred1, Pred2, Pred3, Pred4))
  export.function(result)
})
```

The other way would be to just do:

```
func1(df) -> results
export.function(results)
```

Comment: Is this part of the code correct way of organizing the model result? result <- Reduce(merge, list(Pred1, Pred2, Pred3, Pred4))

Comment: How can you properly the Pred1, Pred2, Pred3 and Pred4 properly that are given within the function (as locals) in a function?

Comment: Actually now that you mention it; I didn't read your code thoroughly enough. I'm not sure this is written the best way possible. Most confusingly is: where does `Mean_model` come from?

Comment: Ohh, actually, it was a typos, it should be the coefficient of each model and I edited the code again and thank you very much for your observation, it should be each model coefficients, Model1$Coefficients, so my problem is, how to extract the output of Pred1, Pred2, Pred3 and Pred4 interms of list or dataframe or in any possible form in that function, thanks again!

Comment: My solution should be the right one for you then; I would just make sure the `str()` of your result and then how to pass it to a `data.frame` which would allow easy saving into a csv via the `export.function()`.

Comment: Thanks, I got what you mean but is it the right way to code like this( result <- Reduce(merge, list(Pred1, Pred2, Pred3, Pred4)) because it gives me unwanted result and takes long time? Is it to concatenate the whole part of the result this way?

Comment: The `Pred` Values are single values no? I haven’t run this code on my end but I can later. But it seems to be integer values in which case I would combine them into a data frame for export with the column name being the `Pred` value so something like `data.frame("Pred1" = Pred1...) -> result`. Then you could just export as a csv.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and for your help and I will try and I think data. frame work as I am expecting numeric values.

Comment: Anytime! Reach out if I can help in anyway later.

Comment: If I change it (result) to Matrix and combine the result using common matrix and include the rest of output columns in the result, how do I go about it? I think Matrix seems to be the best data structure for my result.